# openhtmltopdf : empty spaces added to the table rows when i use noto sans fonts

Tags: javascript, java, openhtmltopdf

I have a very big HTML table in which i have some Hebrew content. I want to generate pdf out of this HTML table using openhtmltopdf library. To fit this big table in A4 size, i am scaling the table and then tries to generate the pdf. The problem comes when i use custom fonts(Noto Sans) to support Hebrew language, it truncates the bottom part of the table. But when i dont use custom fonts then the Hebrew letters coming as # symbol.
**Expected result is With Custom fonts also table should print in A4 size pdf**
**HTML with custom fonts(Noto Sans)**

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">@page {margin: 20px; size: 865px 1224px ;}
 body {transform: scale(0.19992757); transform-origin: left top;} 
p {display: inline;} 
div {overflow:hidden;} 
td {border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px} 
.HiddenCol, .HiddenRow {display: none;} 
table {table-layout:fixed;margin-top: 40px;position: absolute;width: 720px; border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid #dddddd; font-family: 'Almarai Light', 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Noto Sans HK', 'Noto Sans Adlam Unjoined', 'Noto Sans Adlam', 'Noto Sans AnatoHiero', 'Noto Sans Arabic', 'Noto Sans Armenian', 'Noto Sans Avestan', 'Noto Sans Balinese', 'Noto Sans Bamum', 'Noto Sans Batak', 'Noto Sans Bengali', 'Noto Sans', 'Noto Sans Brahmi', 'Noto Sans Buginese', 'Noto Sans Buhid', 'Noto Sans Canadian Aboriginal', 'Noto Sans Carian', 'Noto Sans Chakma', 'Noto Sans Cham', 'Noto Sans Cherokee', 'Noto Sans Coptic', 'Noto Sans Cuneiform', 'Noto Sans Cypriot', 'Noto Sans Deseret', 'Noto Sans Devanagari', 'Noto Sans EgyptHiero', 'Noto Emoji', 'Noto Sans Ethiopic', 'Noto Sans Georgian', 'Noto Sans Glagolitic', 'Noto Sans Gothic', 'Noto Sans Gujarati', 'Noto Sans Gurmukhi', 'Noto Sans Hanunoo', 'Noto Sans Hebrew', 'Noto Sans ImpAramaic', 'Noto Sans InsPahlavi', 'Noto Sans InsParthi', 'Noto Sans Javanese', 'Noto Sans JP', 'Noto Sans Kaithi', 'Noto Sans Kannada', 'Noto Sans Kayah Li', 'Noto Sans Kharoshthi', 'Noto Sans Khmer', 'Noto Sans KR', 'Noto Sans Lao', 'Noto Sans Lepcha', 'Noto Sans Limbu', 'Noto Sans Linear B', 'Noto Sans Lisu', 'Noto Sans Lycian', 'Noto Sans Lydian', 'Noto Sans Malayalam', 'Noto Sans Mandaic', 'Noto Sans Meetei Mayek', 'Noto Sans Mongolian', 'Noto Sans Myanmar', 'Noto Sans NewTaiLue', 'Noto Sans N\'Ko', 'Noto Sans Ogham', 'Noto Sans Ol Chiki', 'Noto Sans Old Italic', 'Noto Sans OldPersian', 'Noto Sans OldSouArab', 'Noto Sans Old Turkic', 'Noto Sans Oriya', 'Noto Sans Osage', 'Noto Sans Osmanya', 'Noto Sans Phags Pa', 'Noto Sans Phoenician', 'Noto Sans Rejang', 'Noto Sans Runic', 'Noto Sans Samaritan', 'Noto Sans Saurashtra', 'Noto Sans SC', 'Noto Sans Shavian', 'Noto Sans Sinhala', 'Noto Sans Sundanese', 'Noto Sans Syloti Nagri', 'Noto Sans Symbols2', 'Noto Sans Symbols', 'Noto Sans Syriac Eastern', 'Noto Sans Syriac Estrangela', 'Noto Sans Syriac Western', 'Noto Sans Tagalog', 'Noto Sans Tagbanwa', 'Noto Sans Tai Le', 'Noto Sans Tai Tham', 'Noto Sans Tai Viet', 'Noto Sans Tamil', 'Noto Sans TC', 'Noto Sans Telugu', 'Noto Sans Thaana', 'Noto Sans Thai', 'Noto Sans Tibetan', 'Noto Sans Tifinagh', 'Noto Sans Ugaritic', 'Noto Sans Vai', 'Noto Sans Yi'; } 
</style></head><body><h3>CT_00002_0000629201_Table 4.wtc</h3><table width="100%" custom-fontsize="18"><tbody><tr><td/><td data-elemtype="BIOT_NUTRIENT_VALUE" data-instance="1"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>במנה (23.4 ג', כ-3 יחידות)</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="SUGAD_NUTRIENT_VALUE" data-instance="1"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="1"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p><b>PROBLEM SOLVER CHART</b></p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="5"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p><b>Alarm/ warning&#xa0;description</b></p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="6"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p><b>Cause</b></p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="7"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p><b>Solution</b></p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="9"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="10"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/><br/><div/>מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="11"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')מצות שומן רוויות (ג')חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/><div/>חומצות שומן רוויות (ג')<div/><br/></p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="13"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Battery empty</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="14"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The battery charge is critically low</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="15"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Connect the pump to the AC power adapter and mains to recharge the battery immediately for 6 hours.&#xa0;<div/>During charging the pump can be used</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="17"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Charging please wait</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="18"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The battery is charging</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="19"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Wait until the battery is charged</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="21"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Door is open</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="22"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The door is not properly closed</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="23"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Close the door&#xa0;</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="25"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Keypad is locked</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="26"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The keypad is locked to prevent unintended button presses</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="27"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Unlock the keypad by pressing i-Button [DO NOT TRANSLATE - IMAGE INFO BUTTON] and SOFT BUTTON 3 simultaneously</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="29"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Last feeding incomplete</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="30"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The pump was turned off before the therapy was completed</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="31"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Press START/PAUSE [DO NOT TRANSLATE - IMAGE START/PAUSE BUTTON ]button to start the same therapy all over.<div/>Press RESUME to continue your active therapy</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="33"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Low battery</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="34"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The battery charge is low</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="35"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Connect the pump to the AC power adapter and mains to recharge the battery immediately for 6 hours.&#xa0;<div/>During charging the pump can be used.</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="37"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>No plug symbol visible, while the pump is connected to the mains</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="38"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The mains outlet does not work.&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/>The AC power adapter is damaged</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="39"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Connect the pump to another mains outlet<div/><br/><div/>Contact your pump provider for replacement<div/>&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/><br/></p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="4"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Occlusion in</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="8"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The pump has detected an occlusion between the pump and the feeding reservoir<div/>&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/>The sensor area is dirty<div/>&#xa0;<div/>Recurring alarm</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="12"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Check the Flocare Infinity giving set between the pump and the reservoir for kinks or other obstructions and correct if found. Restart the pump<div/>&#xa0;<div/>Clean the sensor area<div/>&#xa0;<div/>If alarm persists, replace the Flocare Infinity giving set</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="16"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Occlusion out</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="20"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The pump has detected an occlusion between the pump and the patient<div/>&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/>&#xa0;<div/>The sensor area is dirty<div/>&#xa0;<div/>Recurring alarm</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="24"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Check the Flocare Infinity giving set between the pump and feeding tube for kinks or other obstructions and correct if found<div/>Check your feeding tube for kinks or other obstructions according to your training and correct if found<div/>&#xa0;<div/>Clean the sensor area<div/>&#xa0;<div/>If alarm persists, replace the Flocare Infinity giving set</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="28"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Pump needs attention</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="32"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The pump has been untouched for 3 minutes or more</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="36"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Press any button to acknowledge the warning message</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="40"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Rate not set</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 54" data-instance="54"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>No rate has been programmed when starting a therapy</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 54" data-instance="56"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Program a Rate (mL/h)</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="table cee 41" data-instance="41"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Re-insert giving set</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="table cee 41" data-instance="42"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Giving set not properly installed</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="table cee 41" data-instance="43"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Insert a Flocare Infinity giving set</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="table cell 41" data-instance="43"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Replace giving set</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="table cell 41" data-instance="44"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The giving set has been used for more than 24 hours</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="table cell 41" data-instance="45"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Replace the Flocare Infinity giving set with a new one</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="2"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Set &gt; 24 hrs</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE_CELL" data-instance="3"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Reminder that the giving set has been used for more than 24 hours and needs replacement</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="51"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Replace the Flocare Infinity giving set with a new one.</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="46"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>System failure</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="47"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>The pump has encountered an internal system failure</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="48"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Turn the pump OFF, make sure the pump door is closed and switch the pump back ON.&#xa0;<br/>&#xa0;If the error persists, contact pump provider for replacement</p></span></div></div></td></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="49"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Therapy completed</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="50"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Notification that the pump has completed the delivery of the programmed therapy</p></span></div></div></td><td/></tr><tr><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="52"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Volume not set</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 46" data-instance="53"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>No volume has been programmed when starting a therapy</p></span></div></div></td><td data-elemtype="TABLE CELL 54" data-instance="55"><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><div style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word; margin-left:0px; vertical-align : top "><span style=" display: inline-block; word-wrap:break-word;" dir="ltr"><p>Program a Volume (mL)</p></span></div></div></td></tr></tbody><colgroup><col width="33.33333333333334%"/><col width="33.33333333333334%"/><col width="33.33333333333334%"/></colgroup></table></body></html>
```

**Remove font-family from the HTML for testing without Noto Sans. Below i have added the result for both scenario**

[image: Generate pdf without Noto Sans font]
In this pdf if you see first line content is coming as #

[image: Generated pdf with Noto Sans pdf]

Here everything coming properly but bottom lines are not coming, table is truncated